# Alterar o banco de dados mongodb padrão de uma aplicação Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Olá, estou começando a trabalhar com o [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) e estou tendo dificuldades para definir onde estará localizado a base de dados do mesmo juntamente com o usuário de acesso com autenticação. Procurando na internet, eu encontrei algumas referencias que dizem que devo iniciar a aplicação utilizando este comando ([como nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824944/unable-to-set-mongodb-path-in-meteor-on-window-system)):

```
"MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb meteor run"
```

O problema é, mesmo utilizando as possíveis soluções dadas na pergunta eu ainda não obtive sucesso em fazer com que o Meteor acesse uma base de dados diferente da que ele mesmo crie e, também utilize um usuário de acesso à base.

Alguém tem alguma referência de como posso realmente alterar a base de dados do Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como respondi em outra pergunta sua, basta você customizar seu arquivo `package.json`, criando uma chave "scripts" e colocar os dados do seu banco como preferir. Você pode criar scripts para bancos diferentes, como:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "development": "MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/devdb meteor run",
    "testing": "MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb meteor run",
  }
}
```

Depois, você pode executar em desenvolvimento:

```
$ meteor npm run development
```

E para executar no ambiente de teste:

```
$ meteor npm run testing
```